# Return error message if date format isn't correct

Tags: r

I have a function call specific date format in it. For example, only if format is

```
2002-09-04 16:45:40
```

Then the function will work. Otherwise, it would return an error message such as

```
"Format incorrect"
```

I am wondering how to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
convert.to.date <- function(d) {
  if(is.na(strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))) stop("Format incorrect")
  return(format(d, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', usetz = FALSE))
}

convert.to.date('2002-09-04 16:45:40')
#[1] "2002-09-04 16:45:40"
convert.to.date('09-04-2002 16:45:40')
#Error in convert.to.date("09-04-2002 16:45:40") : Format incorrect
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can write a function to check the format of the date input you are sending using `as.Date` function specifying the `format` argument

```
checkDateFormat <- function(input) {
  x <- as.Date(input, format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )
  if(is.na(x))
     "Format incorrect"
  else
     "Format correct"
}

checkDateFormat("2002-09-04 16:45:40")
#[1] "Format correct"

checkDateFormat("2002-09-04")
#[1] "Format incorrect"

checkDateFormat("2002-09-04 16:45")
#[1] "Format incorrect"
```

Comment: Actually I want to only make `checkDateFormat("2002-09-04 16:45")` to be correct. So I deleted `:%s` in the function. However, when I used `checkDateFormat("2002-09-04 16:45:00")` which is supposed to incorrect but indeed get correct result. What happens here?